# Run a WordPress function on end of video - video.js + WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, video.js

Im trying to implement video.js in a wordpress project im currently working on.

While video.js is great, I'm kind of stuck trying to get the functionality out of it that i NEED.

In a nutshell, once the user has watched the video, I need to update the video to be marked as "watched" on the user's profile. Im trying to achieve this by writing a php function that hooks into a custom field, checks if the video has already been watched, if not, then the function adds the video to the list of watched videos.

User watches video > On ended, run the function inside of my WordPress theme, functions.php

In the video.js API there is a ended event. Where i'm having trouble is getting the wordpress side of things involved.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myPlayer = videojs("session_video");

      videojs("session_video").ready(function(){

      this.on("ended", function(){
        // RUN THE FUNCTION.
      });

    });       
</script>
```

Comment: Is there anyway that you can avoid makeing the request to/through wordpress? Because getting wordpress to accept the ajax in a useful wa is a pain. You can do it with custom pages for instance, but that can be ugly. If you can connect to the database with a vanilla php file (using `wp-settings.php` for config) it will make things easier.

Comment: Can you show how's your implementation? How are you including the player in WP?

Comment: @brasofilo Im implenting the video player by creating a div with the id 'session_video'. In my markup, im getting the video via the wordpress do_shortcode() function. The shortcode is being placed inside my wordpress content editor on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myPlayer = videojs("session_video");

      videojs("session_video").ready(function(){

      this.on("ended", function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "test.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {action: "watched", post_id: <?=$post->ID; ?>},
                success: function(data){
                if(data == "done") {
            $("#result").html('Thanks for watching the video.');
                } else {
            $("#result").html('Something\'s went wrong.');
                }
        }
            });
      });

    });       
</script>
```

And create your test.php file, use `$_POST["post_id"]` to change custom fields etc. and echo "done" if everything is good on php file.

**EDIT**
Example of test.php:

```
<?php
if($_POST["action" == "watched"] && isset($_POST["post_id"])) {
    // do what you want.
    if($everything_is_good) {
        echo "done";
    }
}
?>
```